# Mesh not moving in edit mode

Tags: mesh

When I use my bones in pose mode to move mesh, they don't move in edit mode.
Also how do I use my bones and mesh at the same time?

Comment: If you move bones in Pose mode, they are not supposed to move in Edit mode. The Edit mode will define the rest pose, and when you're in Pose mode you can come back to this rest pose selecting your bones and alt G, alt R, alt S. How do you use your bones and mesh? You have to parent your mesh to your bones.

Comment: Alright thanks for the help! Also how do I make the original bone not move the entire rig

Comment: you don't give enough details and it's too hard to explain all the rigging process in few words, please ask a precise question

Comment: how come whenever I use a bone on a mesh the whole obejct moves and not the part of the mesh I want to move

Comment: because you need to make some correction in Weight Paint mode or with teh Vertex Groups, please share your file or follow some tutorials to understand where is the problem

Comment: How do you setup bones so they move the way you want?

Comment: please follow some tutorials on this topic, it's too large to be answered in few words   ;)

Comment: Yea but whenever I connect the bones it moves the whole body dosent matter where the bone is or what bone it is